# Different parameter within same component not working from second time

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router

I have a navbar component with multiple menu options. I planned to load all the menu content within  single component based on the query parameter value. But it's working only for first time. Not working from second click onwards. Event though the URL of route is changing the view is not getting changed.

My Navbar html code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class=" bg-dark navbar-Light column text-center" style="width: 200PX " >
        <div class="nav-item " >
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: white" routerLink="cricket" (click)="Navigateurl($event, 'cricket')" [queryParams]="{game:'cricket'}">
                <i class='fas fa-skating' style='font-size:30px;color:red'></i>Cricket</a>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: white" routerLink="cricket"  (click)="Navigateurl($event, 'football')" [queryParams]="{game:'football'}">
                    <i class='fas fa-football-ball' style='font-size:30px;color:red'></i> Football</a>
                </div>
            <div class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: white" routerLink="cricket" (click)="Navigateurl($event, 'bikerace')" [queryParams]="{game:'bikerace'}">
                <i class="fas fa-biking"style='font-size:30px;color:red'></i>BikeRace </a>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: white" routerLink="cricket" (click)="Navigateurl($event, 'basketball')" [queryParams]="{game:'basketball'}">
                <i class='fas fa-basketball-ball' style='font-size:30px;color:red'></i>Basketball </a>
            </div></div><div class="column" style="width: 85%">
            </div> 
        </div>
```

Mycomponent.ts file :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cricket',
  templateUrl: './cricket.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cricket.component.css']
})
export class CricketComponent implements OnInit {
  public selectedgame? : string;
  paramsObject? : any;


  constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) {

    this.route.queryParamMap
    .subscribe((params) => {
      this.paramsObject = { ...params.keys, ...params };
    }
  );
  debugger;
  var x = this.paramsObject;
  this.selectedgame = x.params["game"];
  console.log(this.selectedgame + " Hello..");
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   alert(this.selectedgame);  // Not working from second time.
  }

}
```

My component's html file :

```
<div>
    <div *ngIf='selectedgame == "cricket"'>Cricket Div</div>
    <div *ngIf='selectedgame == "football"'>Football Div</div>
    <div *ngIf='selectedgame == "bikerace"'>Bikerace Div</div>
    <div *ngIf='selectedgame == "basketball"'>BasketBall Div</div>

    {{selectedgame}}  // Not changing from second time
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting your assignment inside of your subscribe handler:

```
  constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) {

    this.route.queryParamMap
    .subscribe((params) => {
      this.paramsObject = { ...params.keys, ...params };
      debugger;
      var x = this.paramsObject;
      this.selectedgame = x.params["game"];
      console.log(this.selectedgame + " Hello..");
    });
 }
```

Comment: It's working fine. But why my ngOninit is not calling still ?